# What endpoint HttpBinding on WCF hosted by ServiceHost

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm still learning, and I have a problem connecting to another connected computer in the same network to my simple WCF service using BasicHttpBinding.

Server:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string  endPointAddress = "http://localhost:9942/ServiceTest";
        Uri baseAddress = new Uri(endPointAddress);
        var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(SampleService), baseAddress);
        BasicHttpBinding httpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None);
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ISampleService), httpBinding, "ISampleService");
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Service up and running at:");
        foreach (var ea in host.Description.Endpoints)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ea.Address);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Client:

```
 public class ProxyTestService : ClientBase<ISampleService>, ISampleService   {
   public ProxyTestService(string address)
       :base (new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None),new EndpointAddress($"http://{address}:9942/ServiceTest/ISampleService"))
   {}
   public DateTime GetServerTime()
   {
       return base.Channel.GetServerTime();
   }}
```

When I check on the computer where is the host running it is fine (address = localhost).

However, when I connect from another computer in the network (address = IPComputerHost) there are the following problems:

> There was no endpoint listening at
>   http://192.168.1.111:9942/ServiceTest/ISampleService that could accept
>   the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP
>   action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
>   InnerException: Unable to connect to the remote server

and

> You have tried to create a channel to a service that does not support
>   .Net Framing. It is possible that you are encountering an HTTP
>   endpoint.

When I use NetTcpBinding, everything is correct. What is different in BasicHttpBinding??

Comment: Did you open the port 9942 on your firewall?

Comment: You may need to use the netsh command: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh-contexts.

Comment: netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="ServiceTest9942" dir=in protocol=tcp localport=9942 profile=private remoteip=localsubnet action=allow